# How to define Unicorn configuration for a Helix type serialization folder structure with Docker

Tags: docker, unicorn, serialization

I have followed this article https://gist.github.com/cassidydotdk/47eacabd752d7a84e7e5826531fb0f9e

The docker site is writing to the `C:\unicorn` and the mount volume is set to the `D:\Sitecore\Source\unicorn` but my helix code structure as below

1. `D:\Sitecore\Source\src\Feature\Account\code`
2. `D:\Sitecore\Source\src\Feature\Account\serialization`

In the account feature example, the `unicorn.yml` files should be written to

```
D:\Sitecore\Source\src\Feature\Account\serialization
```

to check in and share with other developers etc however the files from docker are coming to

```
D:\Sitecore\Source\unicorn\Feature\Account\serialization
```

There is a disconnect and missing some configuration here,

Comment: Consider changing your "Helix" serialization structure to match the example provided by Mark's gist. I've found following the pattern by Mark to be easier to package up later on during build/deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no disconnect, but you obviously need to update the `Unicorn.TargetDataStore.config` to match your Helix-type setup. Which, as Michael points out as well, is not what I would recommend.

In case you are wondering; you're basically going to have to mount your entire `.\src` directory into your container to expose all the .yml files; make sure you define a very adequate `.dockerignore` if going down this route.

Also keep in mind; from your question it looks like you may be overlooking this fact; what you define in your `Unicorn.TargetDataStore.config` is a path *relative to your docker container* and NOT your source filesystem as it sits on your host machine.

By default, I recommend not deploying a datastore definition to containers at all. This will cause Unicorn to use `~\App_Data\Unicorn` as its default. You can then volume mount your `.\src` directory to here if you like.

All in all though, bottom line, this is a very clunky approach and you really shouldn't be mixing up your serialised content assets with your source code assets. Make your Unicorn root `.\Unicorn` relative to your GIT repository root, and be done with the hassle.

This best practice is demonstrated in the GIST you linked; here: https://gist.github.com/cassidydotdk/47eacabd752d7a84e7e5826531fb0f9e#file-docker-compose-yml-L7